# is it possible to create android shopping app for magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, api

I am new to magento.I have looked through the internet.There is a lot of rest API's available for Magento version 2.0. but not for the V 1.9.2.
I have looked through below link: `http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html`

But there are only few **REST Api**'s. I would like to know whether I can create fully functional **shopping app** using MAGENTO v1 1.9.2 Rest Api's or not?